# Using text as radio button without using id's or JS

Tags: html, css, radio-button

Is it possible to have a radio button use text to toggle without using id's or javascript? Could you use the 'class' tag instead? This is not a "you should use javascript or id's", but instead a is it possible to do this without them. Any help would be appreciated in resolving this.

Answer (score 0):

Absolutely! There's nothing stopping you from using **[class selectors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Class_selectors)** instead of **[ID selectors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/ID_selectors)**.

Here's a simple radio button that toggles text. It uses pure CSS, and makes use of classes:

```css
.switch-field {
  font-family: "Lucida Grande", Tahoma, Verdana, sans-serif;
  padding: 40px;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.switch-title {
  margin-bottom: 6px;
}

.switch-field input {
    position: absolute !important;
    clip: rect(0, 0, 0, 0);
    height: 1px;
    width: 1px;
    border: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.switch-field label {
  float: left;
}

.switch-field label {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 60px;
  background-color: #e4e4e4;
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: normal;
  text-align: center;
  text-shadow: none;
  padding: 6px 14px;
  border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3), 0 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1);
  box-shadow: inset 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3), 0 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1);
  -webkit-transition: all 0.1s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition:    all 0.1s ease-in-out;
  -ms-transition:     all 0.1s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition:      all 0.1s ease-in-out;
  transition:         all 0.1s ease-in-out;
}

.switch-field label:hover {
    cursor: pointer;
}

.switch-field input:checked + label {
  background-color: #A5DC86;
  -webkit-box-shadow: none;
  box-shadow: none;
}

.switch-field label:first-of-type {
  border-radius: 4px 0 0 4px;
}

.switch-field label:last-of-type {
  border-radius: 0 4px 4px 0;
}
```

```html
<form class="form">
    <div class="switch-field">
      <div class="switch-title">Is this awesome?</div>
      <input type="radio" id="switch_left" name="switch_2" value="yes" checked/>
      <label for="switch_left">Yes</label>
      <input type="radio" id="switch_right" name="switch_2" value="no" />
      <label for="switch_right">No</label>
    </div>
</form>
```

Hope this helps! :)

Comment: but you are still using id's, do I just sub in class for id?

Comment: The IDs are irrelevant when it comes to the CSS declarations; they exist purely to serve the `<label>` `for` attributes. The `for` correlates to an ID, and if you want to make use of a `<label>`, you **must** use an ID in this regard.

Comment: is there a way to do this without using ids though?

Comment: If you are using `<label for>`, then **no**. If you are using another way to generate your button text, then **yes**. Just use class selectors. The above is a working example. If you need something more specific, you'll either need to provide your code, or update your question to **clearly** specify the desired result. For further information, please refer to the help article regarding [**how to ask good questions**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and take the [**tour of the site**](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) :)

Comment: I thought I was clear, my question asked if it is possible WITHOUT using id's or javascript.

Comment: My answer is clear; if you are using `<label for>` to generate text, then you **need** an ID. If you are using another way to generate your button text, then you do **not** need an ID.